# Encountered two children with the same key even with different keys

Tags: reactjs

Could someone explain to me why I'm getting this error?

this is the render function of the component

```
  <Select
    mode="multiple"
    placeholder="Search by City, neighborhood or MLS number..."
    defaultValue={[]}
    style={{ width: 400 }}
    onChange={this.handleChange}>
    <OptGroup label="city" key="city">
      {this.props.cities.map((city, i) => (<Option key={"city"+i} value={city.name}>{city.name}</Option>))}
    </OptGroup>
    <OptGroup label="neighborhood" key="neighborhood">
      {this.props.neighbors.map((neighbor, jj) => (<Option key={"neighbor"+jj} value={neighbor.name}>{neighbor.name}</Option>))}
    </OptGroup>
  </Select>
```

when I remove second OptGroup, the code works fine.

I am using antd.Select.OptGroup from this library

http://ant.design/components/select/

I cant add more than one optgroup otherwise I'll get key error

Comment: Can you please share the `OptGroup` component's render code.

Comment: @RinkeshGolwala I am using antd.Select.OptGroup from this library ant.design/components/select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it,
Values must be different like keys in every option.

this is the correct one

```
    const opt1 =
          <OptGroup label="city" key="city">
            {this.props.cities.map((city, i) => (
              <Option key={"city"+i} value={city.name}>{city.name}</Option>
            ))}
          </OptGroup>
const opt2 =
          <OptGroup label="neighborhood" key="neighborhood">
            {this.props.neighbors.map((neighbor, i) => (
              <Option key={"neighbor"+i} value={neighbor.name+" ("+neighbor.city+")"}>{neighbor.name+" ("+neighbor.city+")"}</Option>
            ))}
          </OptGroup>
```